# Simple memory monitor for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have zero iOS programming experience but I'm good with Android and Java programming. I also know my basics in C++. Here's what the app needs to do:

List out all the current running apps in the phone and display how much Ram each is consuming.
Put the ram usage by each app onto the Logger.

That's it.

It's simple enough and I've read up as much as I can about Objective C and Swift (I can use either) and I've found an interesting [tool here](https://github.com/Shmoopi/iOS-System-Services) that does something similar to what I need to do.

If any of you can give me any advice I'd be forever in debt as I really need to get this done well. If you need anything else, let me know. Thanks a bunch.

Edit: to make myself clear, I'm only asking if this is even possible in iOS and what approach I may take and if there are any tools you recommend. I'm not asking anyone to do this for me.

Comment: What's wrong with the tool you linked? It seems to be some open source classes that you can just drop into your project and use. Then it's just a matter of making a UI for it. If you for whatever reason don't want to use it, it's open source so just have a look at the code.

Comment: @Rick The app is great but it only lists the processes in memory and the total amount of free/used memory. It isn't capable of saying how much memory is being used per app.